# How to change selected tab background in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing sample on Tabs and its working fine but here my question how to show differentiate between selected and non selected Tabs in codenameone. it means after selecting Tab i want to show different background color. 
how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of the selected state of `Tab` Uiid in your Codename One Designer.

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you mean the tab button or the tab content. Assuming the former as Diamond answered, make sure to define the border as empty see https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-9-piece-image-border.html